# C programme for calculating how many students passed an exam

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program for school. So, the task is to write a program that can calculate how many students passed an exam. The student number is unknown (n). I wrote the part where you have to enter the grades and a value for n, but can`t seem to be able to make the part where it counts the number of students that got above 5 - oh, the grades are from 0 >> 10, where 10 is the highest mark.

here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
//introduecerea notelor
    printf("introduceti numarul de studenti care au participat la examen: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    int note[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Studentul %d=", i); scanf("%d", &note[i]);
    }
//afisarea tuturor notelor
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf(" %d", note[i]);
    }
//calcularea numarului de studenti promovati
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ", note[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the last part is a work in progress, so you can ignore it. Any help or hint in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider making your code comments English.

Comment: You can use an `if` statement within a loop such as `if(note[i] > 5) { passed++; }` but of course the variable `passed` must be initialised to `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I made changes as you suggested, now my output displays the same grades, only for the ones under 5 there is a 0. What I need to do is simply have there are let's say 5 out of 8 students that passed. As I said before, I'm new to this. How do I add more code, I doesn't seem possible in the comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int n, i;
        //introduecerea notelor
        printf("introduceti numarul de studenti care au participat la examen: "); scanf("%d", &n);
        int note[n];
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                printf("Studentul %d=", i); scanf("%d", &note[i]);
        }
        //afisarea tuturor notelor
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
                printf("%d ", note[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        //calcularea numarului de studenti promovati
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
                printf("%d ", note[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        int passedGrades=0;
        // We can get total number of students by dividing size of whole array with size of one cell, in this case one cell is 4 bytes
        int totalStudents= sizeof(note)/sizeof(note[0]);

        // Calculate sum of passed students here
        for (size_t i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
                if(note[i]>5) {
                        passedGrades++;
                }
        }
        // And finally print passed students
        printf("%d of %d students had higher grade than 5",passedGrades,totalStudents );
        //getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you already know `totalStudents` is `n`! Isn't `sizeof` a compile-time not run-time operation?

Comment: This works like a charm. I humbly thank you, kind sir.

Comment: It is run-time operation, it will update regarding size of student table you insert. Try to compile and run the code. Thanks.

Comment: Huh? You lost me here. It seems to be working though.

Comment: @JuhoR, why use the non-used array values to calculate anything?  BEWARE that there's a serious bug in your code.  The calculation should go to the whole set of actual students (identified by `n` which should be `<=` _array number of cells_)  but you cannot check over not input array values, as they can have any value (more when the array is an automatic uninitialised variable)  The fact that you get correct results is that initial stack is initialised with zeros in linux, but that's _Undefined Behaviour_.

Comment: I'm unable to see a problem. Could you pin point the actual row where non-used array values are used to calculations. Of course we assume here user input is valid because question was not about input sanitation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a check in third loop

```
int numPassing = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(note[i]>=5) {
        numPassing++;
    } /* if */
} /* for */
printf("%d passed the exam!\n", numPassing);
```

Comment: And what about incrementing some counter on the premises that `note[i] >= 5` ???  The question asked for _the number of passing students_, and not for the list of passing qualifications.  Better if `int passing = 0; if(note[i] >= 5) passing++; printf("%d pass.\n", passing);`